drf-spectacular (swagger) does not show request body of "application/json" in SwaggerUI
I have a login view with the following request body:

However, when I select the content-type "application/json", I only receive the example, without the relevant data from my serializer that is shown in other content-types.

I've tried numerous options to show the request body scheme of the request body, but nothing seems to work.
This is my view:
class LoginSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    username = serializers.CharField(
        min_length=4,   # Minimum length for login
        max_length=50,  # Maximum length for login
        required=True,  # Field is required
        help_text="email of the user",
    )
    password = serializers.CharField(
        min_length=8,   # Minimum length for password
        max_length=128, # Maximum length for password
        required=True,  # Field is required
        style={'input_type': 'password'},  # This will hide the input in browsable API
        write_only=True, # Prevents password from being exposed in responses
        help_text="password of the user",
    )


@extend_schema(examples=[
                    OpenApiExample(
                        'Example',
                        value={"username": "email of the user", "password": "password of the user"},
                        request_only=True,
                    )
],)
class LoginView(GenericAPIView):
    """Authenticates the user via django session authentication cookie"""

    serializer_class = LoginSerializer
    def post(self, request):
        serializer = LoginSerializer(data=request.data)

        username = request.data.get('username')
        password = request.data.get('password')
        if not serializer.is_valid():
            return ValidationError(serializer.errors)

        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is None:
            return ValidationError('Invalid credentials.')

        login(request, user)
        return JsonResponse({'detail': 'Successfully logged in.'})



and these are my drf settings:
SPECTACULAR_SETTINGS = {
    'TITLE': 'Project API',
    'DESCRIPTION': 'Backend Project',
    'VERSION': '1.0.0',
    'SERVE_INCLUDE_SCHEMA': False,
    'SWAGGER_UI_DIST': 'SIDECAR',  # shorthand to use the sidecar instead
    'SWAGGER_UI_FAVICON_HREF': 'SIDECAR',
    'REDOC_DIST': 'SIDECAR',
    'POSTPROCESSING_HOOKS': [
        'drf_spectacular.contrib.djangorestframework_camel_case.camelize_serializer_fields', # ensures compatibility with camelizer
    ],
    "SWAGGER_UI_SETTINGS": {
        "displayRequestDuration": True
    },
    # OTHER SETTINGS
}

# DRF Definitions
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_SCHEMA_CLASS': 'drf_spectacular.openapi.AutoSchema',
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': [
        'djangorestframework_camel_case.render.CamelCaseJSONRenderer',
        'djangorestframework_camel_case.render.CamelCaseBrowsableAPIRenderer',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication', # using Django's Default Session Authentication
    ],
    'DEFAULT_PARSER_CLASSES': [
        'djangorestframework_camel_case.parser.CamelCaseFormParser',
        'djangorestframework_camel_case.parser.CamelCaseJSONParser',
    ],
    'JSON_UNDERSCOREIZE': {
        'no_underscore_before_number': True,
    }
}


My goal is to also show the request body information for JSON requests. How could one achieve this?

The schema - field descriptions, types, etc. - for JSON payloads is on the "Schema" tab: https://i.sstatic.net/6HFywVRB.png (if that's what you meant)

@Helen oh god, I'm turning blind... Thank you so much!
